# Can I use my own driver on Windows without having to ask MS for permission while keeping Secure Boot on?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, uefi, digital-signature, secure-boot

As per the subject :

- I want to write my own kernel mode driver
- I want to be able to use it with Secure Boot on
- I don't want to ask for permission to use it (no WHQL testing or attestation signing)
- This driver isn't intended for publication, personal use only

I've defined my own Secure Boot Platform Key (PK) and know how to populate KEK, db and dbx.

It should be possible, and there are certainly some organisations that need this. As an example, I don't think any country's department of defense would be ready to submit to WHQL or attestation signing for their own hardware running on Windows. In fact, no one should be forced to do this as long as it's not intended for public release.

Hence, would that work ?

1. Add my own public key *P* to the Secure Boot db database
2. Sign my driver with the corresponding private key *K*
3. Run my driver

Or are there additional steps, such as maybe registering *P* in the Windows certificate database ? And/or maybe the certificate should contain some specific x509 extensions, such as a more precise key usage definition ?